# nested xml output from html form using php

Tags: php, xml

I trying to get the following to display as a xml file:

```
<NetAmount currency="GBP">200</NetAmount>
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><CarrierFreightInvoice></CarrierFreightInvoice>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$RID = $_POST['rid'];
$SNDID = $_POST['sndid'];

$RID = htmlentities($RID, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$SNDID = htmlentities($SNDID, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);

$xml->Header = "";
$xml->Header->addChild('RID', $RID);
$xml->Header->addChild('SNDID', $SNDID);

$FreightInvoiceNumber = $_POST['fin'];
$FreightInvoiceDate = $_POST['fid'];
$CarrierReferenceNumber = $_POST['crn'];
$ShipperReferenceNumber = $_POST['srn'];
$NetAmount = $_POST['net'];
$Currency = $_POST['gbp'];


$FreightInvoiceNumber = htmlentities($FreightInvoiceNumber, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$FreightInvoiceDate = htmlentities($FreightInvoiceDate, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$CarrierReferenceNumber = htmlentities($CarrierReferenceNumber, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$ShipperReferenceNumber = htmlentities($ShipperReferenceNumber, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$NetAmount = htmlentities($NetAmount, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$Currency = htmlentities($Currency, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);

$xml->addChild('FreightInvoiceNumber', $FreightInvoiceNumber);
$xml->addChild('FreightInvoiceDate', $FreightInvoiceDate);
$xml->addChild('CarrierReferenceNumber', $CarrierReferenceNumber);
$xml->addChild('ShipperReferenceNumber', $ShipperReferenceNumber);
$xml->addChild('NetAmount', $NetAmount, $Currency);



$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc->save('test.xml');

?>
```

The result is this:

```
<NetAmount xmlns="GBP">200</NetAmount>
```

I've tried a variety of addchild combos but I can't get it working and I'm not expert with this php!
It sort of looks like a php include in the html would sort it out. I would appreciate some pointers....

Comment: Let me get this right you want the `xmlns` as `currency` instead?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `addChild()`, the third parameter is the namespace you want to add the item to (see http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php).  This is why

```
$xml->addChild('NetAmount', $NetAmount, $Currency);
```

adds the currency as the namespace.

If you want to add an attribute then you need to do something like the following.  Create the element and then add the attribute to the new element.

```
$amount = $xml->addChild('NetAmount', $NetAmount);
$amount->addAttribute('currency', $Currency);
```

Comment: That did the trick thanks very much. Now I just need to work out how to name the xml filename from one of the form variables.....